# MongoEngine/MongoDB and Django unable to "add more urls" into urls.py

Tags: python, django

So Everything works fine with my initial 5 urls in the `urls.py` file.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^add/$', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
url(r'^$', PostListView.as_view(), name='list'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>[\w\d]+)/$', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>[\w\d]+)/edit/$', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>[\w\d]+)/delete/$', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete'),
)
```

But when I add an extra line. Let's say

```
url(r'^test/$', test.as_view(), name='test'),
```

I am hit with a 500 Server error page and with debugging it is stating that there is a `validation error?`

```
"test is not a valid objectid"
```

i feel it's an issue with mongoengine but do not what or where.

Comment: The problem might be in your view. Please show us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the rules matter. This rule will match `test/`:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[\w\d]+)/$', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

Define your rules like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^add/$', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
url(r'^$', PostListView.as_view(), name='list'),
url(r'^test/$', test.as_view(), name='test'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>[\w\d]+)/$', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>[\w\d]+)/edit/$', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>[\w\d]+)/delete/$', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete'),
)
```

Comment: Oh my freaking gosh. I have been meddling around with every single file possible for the past 20 hours. I am so incapable... Can you explain to me why I can't add that specific url pattern after the last 3?

Comment: @spvceman Rules are evaluated from the top to the bottom. The first rule that matches the URL will be used. The regex `r'^(?P<pk>[\w\d]+)/$'` matches `test/`, so `PostDetailView.as_view()` will be used if you put your `test` rule after the last three.

Comment: So hypothetically it was associating that "rule" with `test/` automatically?

Comment: @spvceman Exactly. `PostDetailView.as_view()` got executed, but the MongoDB driver raised an error because `test` is not a valid ObjectId.